# understanding components react

Tags: reactjs, components

i am creating react web application for the first time. and i want to ask you guys who have experience in react, for example i am creating registration component, should i create subcomponents for the main registration component, i mean create Navbar, Form, Footer, Somediv component separately for only registration and for login and etc. or i should create root div in registration and create every element in it. which alternative is more better and which technique is used mostly? thanks!

Comment: Per application there will be only one navbar and one footer components

Comment: i am using react-router-dom so i am creating more than one "Page"

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent article on how to approach app architecture with React.  https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html